# are stored procedures really secure against sql injections

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I need to convince someone that he needs to sanitize the user input in addition to the user of stored procedures. well I know I sound crazy but I do not feel comfortable enough with store procedures only. My first reason is that I am able to cause errors in the stored procedure but because of the fact that the application itself handles errors such that error messages are coded it is difficult for outside to understand the what there are. but I still think that this is not secure.

Does any one has a suggestion ? or am I wrong to doubt stored procedures?

Comment: A stored procedure coded to build and execute a dynamic SQL string could be vulnerable to injection attacks. But a procedure built to accept input parameters and use those parameters in non-dynamic SQL is not vulnerable.  Post the definition of the SP in question.

Comment: You can introduce him to [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com) ;) (I know it sounds like a joke, but take a look to the link and see what happens when database inputs are not sanitized)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski what you mean by parameters in non dynamic sql is that is the case where the parameter do not depend on the user input?

Comment: I mean creating the SP like `procedure(IN param1 INT, IN param2 INT)` to use a non-dynamic body like `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (param1, param2)`. Params there are handled by the RDBMS and are not vulnerable.  But doing a similar thing to overflowed's answer below _is_ vulnerable because the input values are concatenated to a string rather than the RDBMS handling them as scalar values.

Comment: @Michael Berkowiski Alright thanks a lot I think I have enough arguments now

Comment: I want to thank all of you guys (Barrank, oveflowed PhilipXT etc..). now I don't know who to choose as best answer..

Comment: Use prepared statements within the stored procedure and to call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not safe on it's own. You can also do in a stored procedure something like this:

```
SET @sql = 'Select * from products where name like ''' +@spinput+''' ';
exec(@sql);
```

With the wrong value in `@spinput` you can inject code.

However you can write stored procedures that are safe against sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use proper parameters, you can still mess with the database.  You could insert a script that goes in as a parameter, but when it's displayed on a web page starts doing something it shouldn't.  Use parameters to ensure your database is used as intended, but also sanitize the output later - never trust user-entered data.

Comment: What you describe is a persistant XSS injection, not a sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Using stored procedures normally protects against SQL injection, but is not the only solution to prevent SQL injections, and it doesn't protect against all forms of SQL injection.

It's not the stored procedure itself that makes the big difference, but parameterised queries, which is the most common way to call a stored procedure. By putting the values used by the query in parameters, you let the database library handle them instead of having to escape them correctly yourself.

It's possible to write code that is safe against SQL injections without using parameterised queries, but it's difficult. You have to know exactly what characters you need to escape in a string for the specific database that you are using, and if you get it wrong you are pretty much as unprotected as if you didn't know about SQL injections at all.

If you use parameterised queries, then the step of sending the values into the database is safe from SQL injection, but the query itself might not be. If the query generates and executes SQL code itself, you have the same problem with escaping strings correctly. It's however not so usual to create SQL code in the SQL code, and if you do it you are very aware of that you are doing it.

Comment: I did, but “using stored procedures normally protects against SQL injection” is wrong.

Comment: It’s like: your code is secure as long as you put it in a function.

Comment: @Gumbo: Ok, if you don't want to explain what you mean, you don't have to. Point ignored.

Comment: You should explain how stored procedures protect against SQL injections.

Comment: @Gumbo: Sigh. Once again; read beyond the first sentence, like a normal person reading the answer. I have explained in the answer exactly what protects against SQL injection. If you refuse to read more than a single sentence of the answer, then that's your problem.